# difference in API/session in Google API billing

Tags: google-api

**Not able to differentiate between price per request and price per session in Google API**

I'm facing difficulty in
understanding some billing related terms for Google API.  I know, this question might be more suited for support directly from Google. I tried but not getting satiesfactory response. 
I was going through this URL:

https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/understanding-cost-of-use#ac-per-character

Here both 'price per request' and 'price per session' has been provided.
While I understand the difference between request and session, my question
is related to example provided in the same link, which is like this :
Places Autocomplete Request (input=”paris”, session_token: XYZ)

What I know, in google API, we just pass an API KEY to get results, but above seem to have  required session_token. This has confused me. How can I pass session_token,  when google has provided just an API KEY to me after creating billing account?

Is API key same as Session_token or does that mean, I need to get session token after 'first' passing API_KEY via code. 
I'm not able to find good example explaining this till now.

Thanks for your help !!

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you'd put the API key into the URL to identify the project.
You'd put the session token (ideally, a [version 4 UUID](https://www.uuidgenerator.net/version4)) into the request body to bundle (combine) requests that are sent to different resources but still related to each other (e.g. sending requests to the Autocomplete API followed by a closing request sent to the Place Deatails API → one session). The Autocomplete API and the Place Details API are two different resources (sub-APIs) of the Places API.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/place-session-tokens

For each session, you'll need a new session token. The API key can stay the same.

That way, Google will apply session-based billing, which is cheaper than request-based billing.